# footer designing with flexbox

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I'm trying to make a footer for my website for a school project using flexbox and SCSS, but it's not working as expected.

What i'm trying to get de `.footer-main` in the center. In the `.footer-end` I want to keep the `h2` on the left and get the `ul` on the right. I tried `text-align: center;`, `align-items: center;` & `justify-content: center;` but those didn't work.

```
<footer>
        <section class="footer-main">
            <p>name name</p>
          
            <a href="mailto:123@mail.com">
               123@mail.com
            </a>
    
            <p>place</p>

            <p>province, country</p>
        </section>
        
        <hr>

        <section class="footer-end">
            <h2>copyright 2023</h2>
    
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="link">
                        link
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="link">
                        link
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </footer>
```

```
footer {
    padding: 10px;
    line-height: 80%;
    .footer-main {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;

    }
    .footer-end {
        display: flex;
    }
    ul {
        display: flex;
        width: 10vh;
        text-decoration: none;
        list-style: none;

        a {
            list-style: none;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Start with adding `justify-content: space-between;` to the `.footer-end` selector - it will align `h2` and `ul` on both ends of the container.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change your html a bit and add flex in the appropriate places

```css
footer {
    padding: 10px;
    line-height: 80%;
}
.footer-main {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    
}

.footer-end {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    
}
ul {
    display: flex;    
    width: 10vh;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
   
    }
    
    li{
    margin-right:5px;}

a {
    list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<footer>
        
        
        <hr>

        <section class="footer-end">
            <h2>copyright 2023</h2>
            
            <div class="footer-main">
            <p>name name</p>
          
            <a href="mailto:123@mail.com">
               123@mail.com
            </a>
    
            <p>place</p>

            <p>province, country</p>
        </div>
            
    
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="link">
                        link
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="link">
                        link
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>
        <hr>
    </footer>
```